# How to Delete zip folder from specific folder in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

unlink not working

```
unlink(public_path('/uploads/360_files/tiles.zip'));
\File::delete(public_path('/uploads/360_files/tiles.zip'));
```

Please help me

Comment: Are you sure you uploaded to the /public directory? Please show your upload code so we can see if you uploaded correctly. `public_path()` shows to the /public dir, uploads using the public driver are uploaded to storage/app/public

Comment: $fileNM = $request->tiles_folder->getClientOriginalName(); 
                $request->tiles_folder->getClientOriginalExtension();
$destinationPath = public_path('/uploads/360_files/'.$request->restaurant_id.'/');
                                
$upload_status = $request->tiles_folder->move($destinationPath, $fileNM);

Answer (score 1):

By using laravel Storage system :

```
Storage::disk('your-drive')->delete('folder_path/yourzip.zip');
```

Delete file from public path :

```
File::delete(public_path().'/yourfile.zip');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can delete files and folder using laravel Storage facade like

Storage::delete('file.jpg');

If you want you can delete file from specific disk

Storage::disk('s3')->delete('folder_path/file_name.jpg');

You can delete specific folder like

Storage::deleteDirectory($directory);